# How to obtain Eclipse locationURI for the extension framework?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am writing a Plugin and want to add an entry in the contextmenu that shall only be visible in the ContentOutline. 
I found the following locationUri that adds my new command for all context menus

`popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any?after=additions`

changing this locationUri to popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.ContentOutline?after=additions did not work. How can I find these locationUri?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried with this: 
popup:org.eclipse.ui.views.ContentOutline?after=additions

Comment: Have you tried using popup:org.eclipse.ui.views.ContentOutline#PopupMenu?after=additions <- ? Not much but I guess is worth the try.

Answer (score 0):

Answering for future generations

If you are only interested in the outline for Java code, the locationURI for the JavaOutlinePage (which implements the IContentOutlinePage) is

popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.outline

The JavaDoc at the top of the JavaOutlinePage's file includes the line:

"Publishes its context menu under `JavaPlugin.getDefault().getPluginId() + ".outline"`."

Quickly printing out JavaPlugin.getDefault().getPluginId() gave "org.eclipse.jdt.ui".